# How would you build a regex that splits a paragraph into sentences, but does not split on any punctuation that is inside <>?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, sentence

Currently I have this regex to split a paragraph into sentences: `/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g`. The issue though is that my paragraphs aren't just paragraphs of text. I have links in them like this:

```
This is text and here is a <value="link" href="http://link.com?param=test"> which directs to another page. So I don't want to split at the anything inside the link above.
```

I want to split that into an array like:

```
['This is text and here is a <value="link" href="http://link.com?param=test"> which directs to another page.', 'So I don't want to split at the anything inside the link above.']
```

What regex would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(.+?[\.!\?](?!.+?>)\s*)
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, but forgets about the last text if it doesn't terminate in the expected punctuation when splitting.